# Given Lie algebra data, how to find its group in maplesoft software?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, maple

```
LD3:=[[e1, e2]=e4,[e1, e3]=e5,[e1, e4]=-e2,[e1, e5]=-e3,[e2, e3]=-e6,[e2, e4]=-e1,[e2, e6]=-e3,[e3, e5]=-e1 

[e3, e6]=e2,[e4, e5]=-e6,[e4, e6]=-e5,[e5, e6]=e4],[C12, C13, C14, C23, C24, C34],[b12, b13, b14, b23, b24, b34]
```

How can I find the corresponding group for the Lie algebra given in the picture (using maplesoft software)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The commands LiesThirdTheorem and Action, from the DifferentialGeometry:-GroupActions package, might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please give an example of finding a group from lie algebra data.  Lie algebra data is attached in the question.

Comment: Also the command Lies Third Theorem works only for Solvable representations. What to for unsolvable representation.